# Strange colors show up on my objects

Tags: modeling

[image]I made a circle and extruded it to make a wheel but then strange colors (orange,green,blue) show up on my object...I tried to reset ewerything to standard but the colors still show up.

Comment: Adding a screenshot can help

Comment: Do you have some kind of material on it? After all your viewport shading is set to _Material Preview_, so without more information I can only guess this is a preview of the material...?

Comment: It does not matter if i switch , it's still there...i know its a setting but not were...

Comment: could you please pack your images and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: ok...packed it and uploaded it as T-72-8.blend...Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

That's the Mesh Analysis enabled in the Overhang mode.

You can disable it by unticking Mesh Analysis in Viewport Overlays (in Edit Mode).

[image]

More info: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/mesh_analysis.html

Comment: Ahhh....thanks...so simple...there one have for clicking without knowing...Great now i can continue...that was a bit enoying to see all the time.:)